# CSS creating image links next to each other

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create a set of four icons which link to the rest of the website. At the moment the coding all works fine until all four are set up in which then only one works.

I am using foundation to create a responsive website.

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
            <div id="portfolio_link">
            <a href="#portfolio_page">
                <img src="img/portfolio.png" style="width:80px">
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
            <div id="contact_link">
            <a href="#contact_page">
                <img src="img/Contact.png" style="width:80px">
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
             <div id="home_link">
            <a href="#home_page">
                <img src="img/home.png" style="width:87px">
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
            <div id="about_link">
            <a href="#about_page">
                <img src="img/about.png" style="width:80px">
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Define "works". Also, where is the relevant CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your columns set to in your _settings.scss? If you have large-6, this is going to take up 50% of your page. You can either set each of those to large-3, or change your total-columns to 24.

```
$total-columns: 12;
```